# Getting the full path the script is currently running in [Python]

Tags: python, path

I am trying to get the path where the script is currently executed.
I found a lot of answers regarding this question, so my question is what's the best solution or even what the differences between all these are:

- `os.getcwd()`
- `__file__`
- `os.path.dirname(__file__)`
- `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`
- `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath( __file__ ))`
- `os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])`
- `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))`

Especially I want to know, what's the best way of getting the path when the script is put into an .exe file, for example if I want to access files, which are in the same directory as the .exe.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**
I am working on windows.

Comment: When built into an exe using PyInstaller, you would use `sys.executable`.

Comment: Working on windows, I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain to you by explaining the outputs of all the commands you mentioned by running them in Windows.

Nothing special here, just importing some modules. Importing `numpy` to test the commands.

```
In [1]: import os
   ...: import sys
   ...: import numpy
```

This gives the current working directory in which your process/program is executing. (detailed tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_getcwd.htm))

```
In [2]: os.getcwd()
Out[2]: 'C:\\Users\\<username>'
```

This tells which file the module is loaded from which file.

```
In [3]: numpy.__file__
Out[3]: 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'
```

The path of the loaded file for the module, it can be a relative path.

```
In [4]: os.path.dirname(numpy.__file__)
Out[4]: 'C:\\Users\\Punit Singh\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy'
```

The actual path of the loaded file for the module. See the difference from previous in `lib` and `Lib`. The folder name actually starts from the capital letter.

```
In [5]: os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(numpy.__file__))
Out[5]: 'C:\\Users\\Punit Singh\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy'
```

This is the absolute path, you'll see the difference when you'll run this in Linux. It starts with the root folder denoted by `\`.

```
In [6]: os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(numpy.__file__))
Out[6]: 'C:\\Users\\Punit Singh\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy'
```

`[7]` and `[8]` respectively give the path and absolute path of the file which is currently executing, here `sys.argv[0]` returns the file which is currently executing, since currently, I am running ipython, it is ipython.exe shown in `[9]`. (detailed tutorial [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-sys-argv-in-python/))

```
In [7]: os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
Out[7]: 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\anaconda3\\Scripts'

In [8]: os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
Out[8]: 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\anaconda3\\Scripts'

In [9]: sys.argv[0]
Out[9]: 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\ipython'
```

This gives the absolute path of the executable binary for the Python interpreter (documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable))

```
In [10]: sys.executable
Out[10]: 'C:\\Users\\Punit Singh\\anaconda3\\python.exe'
```

Now coming to your requirement, I understand that you need to access files where this `ipython.exe` as shown in `[9]` is located, so you can use commands mentioned in `[7]` or `[8]`.

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant answer! I have been using ```sys.argv[0]``` for a while, what do you think about ```sys.executable```?

Comment: I've updated the answer with `sys.executable` and also corrected a mistake I made in explaining `sys.argv[0]`, please re-read that section.